# how to access images in whatsapp running inside dual space

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, xiaomi, android-10

I am using Whatsapp inside Dual Space in Xiaomi Mi A3 mobile.
I am not able to find the images downloaded inside Whatsapp inside Dual space. Where can I find them.
Internal Storage/Android/data/com.ludashi.dualspace/files
has 2 folder Movies,crashinfo
and folder
Internal Storage/Android/data/com.ludashi.dualspace/cache/
has 2 folder video-cache and UnityAdsCache.

So I don't see Whatsapp folder inside Dual space. What can I do to find images of Whatsapp running in Dual space.